# Как получить результат функции в JS?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Если говорить точнее, то результат асинхронного запроса, который происходит внутри функции.

Код:

```
function query(my){
    $.post('https://...', { var1: "1", var2: my}, function(go){
        return go;
    })
    .done(function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        return d;
    })
    ;
}
```

Где в `.done` вызывается `console.log()` там находится нужная информация.

Как её достать что бы она оказалась в переменной `main` если `main = query(55);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success

Comment: @Yaant да верно, решение оттуда помогло, можно закрыть